# Prevent webpack from running multiple dev-server sockets

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm having problems with multiple copies of `webpack-dev-server/client` on a page that's including multiple chunks.

```js
{
  entry: {
    "common": "./src/common.js",
    "example-post": "./src/example-post/index.js",
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      chunks: ["common", "example-post"]
    })
  ]
}
```

Something is breaking the error overlay plugin on all the pages that included multiple chunks.

I noticed that the `[WDS] Live Reloading enabled.` message was showing multiple times on those pages.

Had a quick look in the bundle analyzer and sure enough, there's a full copy of `webpack-dev-server/client` (and all of its dependencies) in each bundle.

[image]

It's understandable that this is the default, so that each chunk could be used separately.

Have been trying to move the dev server code into its own chunk via `optimization.splitChunks` but even when I deduplicate the code with a `/webpack-dev-server/` chunk, there are still multiple dev server sockets open.

How can I ensure that only one socket is opened, and shared across all chunks on the page?

Comment: something is wrong with your configuration. Pls provide entire config. And: are you running webpack-dev-server via CLI or at your own NodeJS via API?

Answer (score 0):

According to Google developers document you must [remove duplicate code](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-javascript/code-splitting#removing_duplicate_code).
Added below config to your webpack config:

```js
// ...
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        // Split vendor code to its own chunk(s)
        vendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/i,
          chunks: "all"
        },
        // Split code common to all chunks to its own chunk
        commons: {
          name: "commons",    // The name of the chunk containing all common code
          chunks: "initial",  // TODO: Document
          minChunks: 2        // This is the number of modules
        }
      }
    },
  },
// ...
```